# How to approach parsing through a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, parsing, code-analysis, lexer

I want to parse through a javascript and find all the variable declarations, attributions, and calls to functions from a specific library.

What would be the best approach:regular expressions, lexer, use something already done that does that (does it exist?)....?

What I want in fact is to be assured that an object namespace and methods are not modified, and this through a static analysis.

Comment: The browser already does this pretty well. You can use an inspector/profiler to see the result of the parsing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it with regexes and probably you also do not want to write you own implementation of [ecma-standard 262](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) (It is a total overkill).
As for me I dig google's V8 javascript engine, more precisely [PyV8](http://code.google.com/p/pyv8/). I suggest you can use it.

If you had problems there is the code I used to install (pip installation had an error for my x64 system, so I used sources):

```
apt-get install subversion scons libboost-python-dev
svn checkout http://v8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ v8
svn checkout http://pyv8.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ pyv8
cd v8
export PyV8=`pwd`
cd ../pyv8
sudo python setup.py build
sudo python setup.py install
```

As I remember these commands did not make errors for me. (I copypasted it but it worked)

**Answer to the question itself:**
More complex hello wolrd example, list some varibales of the global object:

```
import PyV8

class Global(PyV8.JSClass):      # define a compatible javascript class
    def hello(self):               # define a method
        print "Hello World"

    def alert(self, message): # my own alert function
        print type(message), '  ', message

    @property
    def GObject(self): return self

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        super(Global, self).__setattr__(key, value)
        print key, '=', value

G = Global()
ctxt = PyV8.JSContext(G)
ctxt.enter()
ctxt.eval("var a=hello; GObject.b=1.0; a();")
list_all_cmd = '''for (myKey in GObject){
alert(GObject[myKey]);
}'''
ctxt.eval(list_all_cmd)
ctxt.leave()
```

(In browsers you should call you global object - Window)
This code will output:

```
b = 1
Hello World
<class '__main__.Global'>    <__main__.Global object at 0x7f202c9159d0>
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<type 'int'>    1
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
<class '_PyV8.JSFunction'>    function () { [native code] }
```

Comment: Did you use pyV8 for Windows or Linux?

Comment: I had some problems with installing boost.python

Comment: So in what format  builds the output can I trace some variables in that? Can you give a link with an example on how can be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Rhino](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino) from Mozilla. It is a Javascript implementation written in Java. 1.7R3 release onwards have a new AST API. The classes are available in org.mozilla.javascript.ast

If you want to do this in Javascript, please see this discussion [JavaScript parser in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554519/javascript-parser-in-javascript)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am already considering pynoceros(python rhino port), pynarcissus, and pyV8 so thanks for confirming my aproach :), also thanks for the sugestion with jslint parser maybe I can also find a jslint port for python and look there in the regular expressions. I see that it builds from code objects like `<pynoceros.ScriptOrFnNode.ScriptOrFnNode object at 0xb73f2d2c>` any ideea how can I trace a variable through that? I don't know how to work effectively with it.