# jshint - Create custom warnings/rules

Tags: javascript, jshint

Is it possible to create a custom jshint rule, add it to existing inbuilt rules, configure it (on or off) in our projects?

Is jshint extendable, like how we create our own custom tasks in Grunt?

Sometimes we need to enforce a javascript coding practice just in our environment.  For example, we want to enforce our developers to use Date.now() instead of Date.getTime().

Comment: See this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11816713/static-analysis-with-custom-rules-for-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should consider using [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) in that case.

Every rule is standalone. [Even the default rules](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/tree/master/lib/rules). So you could take one of the default rules as a blueprint, and write your own.

Comment: Thanks DerZyklop.  This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 4):

There's some vague reference to how to do this in the jshint-next project on GitHub, which was apparently merged back into jshint proper at some point.

https://github.com/jshint/jshint-next/wiki/Design

Comment: `if (ident.name && ident.name.slice(0, 5) !== "kitty")
      linter.report.addError("C001", "More cats please.");` Classic.