# Treat the use of @author as code style violation

Tags: javascript, jslint, jshint, eslint, static-code-analysis

**Goal:**

Issue a warning in case an `@author` tag is used anywhere inside the `.js` files in the project.

**Question:**

Is it something that `jshint` or other static code check tools can help with? If not, what options do I have?

**Description:**

I completely agree with Paul's answer at [Javadoc @author tag good practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269843/javadoc-author-tag-good-practices) thread and treat `@author` tag as an unnecessary noise.

And, in the Python world, I've seen people checking for the tag usage. For example, [`Openstack Style Guidelines`](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/hacking/) explicitly state not use `@author` tag. They have developed a set of custom `flake8` checks which include:

```
[H105] Don’t use author tags.
```

Now, I'm trying to solve the same problem in JavaScript.

Example (this should not pass a code quality check):

```
/**
 * @author John Smith <john@smith.com>
 */

'use strict';
```

Comment: No, jshint can't do that. Just do a grep across the sources looking for `@author`. If you want you could put that in a git pre-commit hook. Or, you could hack JSDoc to error out when creating docs if it encounters `@author`.

Comment: @torazaburo thank you for the useful comment, it can actually be a legitimate answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, jshint can't do that. Just do a grep across the sources looking for @author. If you want you could put that in a git pre-commit hook. Or, you could hack JSDoc to error out when creating docs if it encounters @author.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry, I meant to try this out before posting an answer, but the bounty's almost up.  ;^)

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24153165/1028230) claims that there's a way to write your own JSHint module.

- It looks like it was done in a branch, https://github.com/jshint/jshint-next/wiki/Design
- Its [readme](https://github.com/jshint/jshint-next) says, *This project is obsolete. It was merged into the main repository,* so that's a good sign.

Let's pretend it works as advertised and has been merged back in.

**[Great instructions here](https://github.com/jshint/jshint-next/wiki/Design),** though note that those are on the "jshint-next" site.

Example code from that page:

```
// This module errs on any identifier that doesn't starts with 'kitty'.
function myModule(linter) {
  linter.on("Identifier", function (ident) {
    if (ident.name && ident.name.slice(0, 5) !== "kitty")
      linter.report.addError("C001", "More cats please.");
  });
}
```

Here's from the initial section on how to set up a linter:

```
var Linter = require("jshint").Linter;
var code   = "<your beautiful JavaScript code here>";

// Create a new instance of Linter.
var linter = new Linter(code);

// Now you can teach JSHint about your predefined variables.
// Note that default JavaScript identifiers are already there.
linter.addGlobals({
  jQuery:   false,
  MyPlugin: true
});

// If you have any JSHint extensions, you can attach them
// to the current instance.
linter.addModule(myModule);

// Finally, parse your code.
linter.parse();
```

I realize that's pretty generic (you'd still need to research `linter.on` options beyond `Identifier`; there's a `String` too, eg), but it looks pretty promising. Again, you can see how to integrate using the instructions [above](https://github.com/jshint/jshint-next/wiki/Design).  And it looks like this is the format that's [used in `style.js`](https://github.com/jshint/jshint/blob/9caf106648ecad90d4e1d79a9278409bf5c2d9c4/src/style.js).

I have **not** tried this out yet. Just haven't had time at home; apologies.

Is there a specific reason torazaburo's "Just `grep` it" answer doesn't work? Do you need this to be part of a code quality workflow? If so, this "write your own module" would seem to be the way to go.

There are also pretty obvious ways to hack up JSLint, if you're up for it, but I'm not sure Crockford would appreciate that.  ;^)

Comment: Ha, of course the bounty is awarded *as* I'm writing this answer. That's what I get.

Comment: :) Don't worry about it - I'll try this out and get back to you. Thank you very much. (out of upvotes for today, but this definitely deserves one)

Comment: FYI, I've posted how I've solved it with `ESLint` (note the simplicity). Bounty goes to you anyway. Thank you for looking into this.

Answer (score 6):

Solved it with [`ESLint` package](http://eslint.org/) - a pluggable linting utility for JavaScript.

Created a [custom rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/) (note *how simple it is*) and saved it to `rules/no-author.js`:

```
/**
 * @fileoverview A rule to disallow @author tag in code
 */

module.exports = function (context) {
    "use strict";
    function checkComment(node) {
        var commentToCheck = node.value.toLowerCase().trim();

        if (commentToCheck.indexOf("@author") !== -1) {
            context.report(node, "A comment unexpectedly contains @author.");
        }
    }

    return {
        "BlockComment": checkComment,
        "LineComment": checkComment
    };
};
```

Now, imagine I have a `test.js` file that violates the use of `@author` tag:

```
/**
 * @author John Smith <john@smith.com>
 */
```

And see how the rule is applied:

```
$ eslint test.js --rulesdir=rules/ --rule='no-author: 2'

test.js
  1:0  error  A comment unexpectedly contains @author  no-author

✖ 1 problem
```

FYI, `no-author: 2` here [means](http://eslint.org/docs/configuring/) to turn the rule on as an error (exit code is 1 when triggered).