# combine two PMD checks

Tags: xpath, extend, pmd, ancestor

I met a problem while using PMD to check my code errors. I do not know how to satisfy two requirements at the same time. For example, if I want to check a method named ABC not existing in file extends from BCD. I know how to check whether ABC exists or whether it extends from BCD separately using PMD.

Like this:

```
//PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name [@Image = "ABC"];
//ExtendsList/ClassOrInterfaceType [@Image != "BCD"];
```

now, is there anyway that I can check these two together. For example, I want it no ABC in class extends BCD. It seems I cannot simply use things like and to connect this two Xpath queries. Also, I noticed I can use | to get connected with them, but | works as or. I need an and here instead of or.

**Edit:**

I tried something like this:

```
//PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image = "ABC"]
 [//ancestor::ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration/ExtendsList/
                                     ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image != "BCD"]]
```

Which seems like it works for me at least. But I am still not 100% sure if this is the correct way since I just tried this out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your edit should work, although note that `ancestor` axis will recurse all parent nodes, so it should not be introduced with '//'.

Another alternative is to base the Xpath from a common ancestor (e.g. `ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration`) and then use `and` to ensure the two criteria are met. Since it seems that you are merely testing for the presence of a node meeting both criteria, I guess it doesn't really matter what the resultant expression / node-set actually returns:

```
//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[ExtendsList/ClassOrInterfaceType[@Image != "BCD"] 
                  and descendant::PrimaryExpression/PrimaryPrefix/Name[@Image = "ABC"]]
```

If however you do need to select a specific node upon success, just append the node's path, relative to `ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration`:

```
//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[... predicate ...]/Some/Path/Here
```

You could also apply a function like `count()` to determine the number of nodes meeting the criteria:

```
count(//ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration[... predicate ...])
```

And then evaluate the expression.

(Caveat - I'm not familiar with the PMD layout)

[I've put some examples](http://xsltransform.net/eiZQaG6) showing the effects of `//ancestor::` vs `ancestor::` and my alternative.